# How do I solve for this normal distribution variable mathematically and in R?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, absolute-value

This is the question I have attempted to answer but unsure about my solution:

If $X$ is $N(650,625)$, find a constant $c>0$ such that $P(|X−650|≤c)=0.9544.$

[My Proposed Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xySqE.jpg)

The expected answer is $c=50$ but I have tried with different combinations of `qnorm()` including `qnorm(0.9772)`  and `qnorm(0.9772, 650,25)` and I am not arriving at this outcome.

Comment: The value you obtain for `qnorm(0.9772, 650, 625)` should be $650+c$ instead.

Comment: Thank you @player3236. I have combed the whole internet for this :)

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was wrong as I thought you meant $\sigma=625$ not $\sigma^2=625$, I have deleted it now. However, just to provide you an analytic solution:  $P(|X-\mu|\le c) = \text{erf}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)$. Therefore $c=\sqrt{2}\cdot 25\cdot\text{erf}^{-1}(0.9544)= 49.977$